# How to regex match strings that do not contain a set of substrings

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I am looking through 1000s of JSON files, and all of them have a property on them like this: `"value": {some number}`,

I want to grep all of these JSON files, and match all cases where `value` is NOT equal to `1`,`2`, or `3`. So if `"value": 10`? Grep should return that. `"value": 1`? Grep should not return that.

The best regex I can get is `.*\"value\": ((?!1)|(?!2)|(?!3))` But I must not know enough have negative lookaheads to use this correctly, am I close? Is there a better way to do NOT operations in regex?

[Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) is the closest answer I've found, but I cannot figure out how to apply it to this case where I have a set of substrings.

Comment: Regex is not the right tool to parse JSON. Better add a reproductible example with sample JSON input and expected output. The basic tool for this is `jq`

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you familiar with any programming/scripting language? Chances are pretty good that the language you are most familiar with has at least _one_ JSON library so that you can parse these  files safely. Regex is not a good tool for parsing JSON.

Comment: I agree that regex/grep is not ideal, but if I have thousands of individual JSON files, I'm not sure how I'm loading all thousands of those JSON files into a python script, parsing the JSON, and then outputting the ones that have a `value != 1,2, or 3`. Does `jq` have a way for me to search through a set of directories for all my JSON files?

Answer (score 0):

With [jq](/questions/tagged/jq):

#### Input file:

```
cat file.json
[
    {
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "value": 3
    },
    {
        "value": 4
    },
    {
        "value": 5
    },
    {
        "value": 6
    },
    {
        "value": 7
    }
]
```

#### Output:

```
jq '.[] | select( .value != 1 and .value != 2 and .value != 3 )' file.json
{
  "value": 4
}
{
  "value": 5
}
{
  "value": 6
}
{
  "value": 7
}
```

Will works too with multiple JSON files.

Comment: For jq beinners: some things you can do with jq: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/jq-command-json . P.S. The jq package may not be installed by default on your system.